# created_at field sometimes becomes nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I think `created_at` is always set to the time a record created in by ActiveRecord, but I found some records are created with null `created_at`.
Are there any condition to cause this?

Comment: You say `updated_at` in question title and `created_at` in the body. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Perhaps `created_at` was migrated in after those records already existed?

Comment: No, these records are saved after all migrations.

Comment: No answer! That's shocking, I am having this issue as well! Time to dig deeper.

Comment: Can you provide any more context for your question? Models, schema, relevant code? I've never seen this happen in any of my rails projects.

Answer (score 1):

These columns created_at, updated_at, created_on, updated_on are automatically handled for you by rails.

However, there are a few notes:

1. Do not change the attr's value (i.e. `created_at` **should be nil before create** and **shouldn't be changed before update**). Otherwise, ActiveRecord won't update attr's value with the current time.
2. Check that your `<ClassName>.record_timestamps` is set to true.

Also, I'd suggest to you to add not-null constraint to these columns:

```
change_column :<table_name>, :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
```

This way you will be sure that this column always have a not-null value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` on your model?

Because without those basic protections, any update request could be setting these otherwise unvalidated & unprotected attributes.

[Mass-assignment security](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i could think of right now is that maybe you are overwriting the `created_at` attribute in your view.

```
<%= t.text_field :created_at %>
```

And the value you are passing when submitting the form is not being correctly converted by ActiveRecord, becoming `nil`.
The `created_at` is not meant to be manipulated, it is better to create another field like `creation_date` and leave it to be populated by default.
But this is just a guess.