# Rails 3.2.8 model before_save not working properly under heavy server load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

A few days ago our site experienced a spike in traffic. While we scaled up to handle the load our single server was maxed out and requests started timing out. During that time records were still being created by some requests. The problem comes from the following model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_published_at
  def set_published_at
    if published? && published_changed?
      self.published_at = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason some lists published during this time had published=true but published_at=nil.

There are numerous other callbacks and one observer on this model, but none of them affect the published_at attribute. This happened on five records concentrated to a five minute window.

How the published_at attribute be null and the model still have been saved with published=true?

Comment: Not an answer, but why don't you have a validation on the published_at field to ensure that it's present? That might've helped track it down.

Comment: Didn't seem relevant or necessary to add a validation when this was written, since it is set by code (reliably until this incident) in a before_save. It is never updated again and cannot be edited by the user.

Comment: Validations exist to make sure your data is never inconsistent, not just to make sure that users don't enter bad data! :)

Comment: I would argue that validations exist to provide useful error messages, database constraints exist to keep data in line. ;) point taken. But to further the point, if I can't rely on before_save why should I expect to rely on validate? I would really like to understand the core of how this happened rather than just cover it up and refuse it when it happens.

Comment: That's fair! But database constraints would have solved the issue too. Anyhow. You *should* be able to expect it to run; I've never seen it fail, even under high load.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition problem.  Where the `published` attribute are set to true or false?  If `published` are changed to false, is `published_at` automatically set back to null?

Comment: `published` is true on these records (hence the problem) and `published_at` is only ever changed by that line. `published_at` isn't attr_protected, so our JS heavy front end does send it back down with the PUT (which was an oversight and will be remedied). I can see a race condition happening such that the request to publish gets processed before an intermediate update request, however if that were the case the model would fail validation as we DO have validations enforcing that `published` is never set back to false.

Comment: Not answering your question, but if `published` is never set back to false means `published_at` could only be set once so I would suggest to have simpler code like `self.published_at ||= Time.now if published?`.

Comment: Perfectly valid refactor

Comment: Maybe it's connected with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323995/created-at-field-sometimes-becomes-nil) but no answer there, sorry.

Comment: I should also add that we are using optimistic locking on this model.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for some reason `published? && published_changed?` evaluated to `false` when you were under heavy load.

Comment: That could be the issue, but why? And how could the issue be prevented?

Comment: Oh i see-- I missed the thing about published=true in your original question. Is the database (indpendent of rails) set to have published=true by default, and/or based on other conditions? Is it possible that something else in the code is niling published_at after the fact, or setting published to true after the fact?

Comment: Nope, nowhere else sets published_at. The only possibility I see was some sort of async save problem, but optimistic locking and validations should have prevented that.