# Rails after_create created_at not set on created objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have on my Message model, an after_create which creates a new instance of a Notification like such.

```
after_create :send_notification

def send_notification
  n = Notification.new :name => "#{self.sender.smart_name} sent you a message:", :user_id => self.receiver_id, :notification_type => 'message', :subject => self.subject
  n.save
end
```

However, the objects that are created all have their created_at and updated_at set to nil.

```
#<Notification:0x0000000c486208
  id: 123123,
  user_id: 3423,
  name: "I sent you a message:\n" + "10:27",
  notification_type: "message",
  created_at: nil,
  updated_at: nil>
```

I've checked to see that the model.record_timestamps is set to true based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323995/created-at-field-sometimes-becomes-nil).

I don't have anything set on active_record as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255272/rails-4-model-returns-always-nil).

I'm using Mysql on Rails 4.

Comment: It looks like they're not saving at all. `.save` fails silently--try using `.save!`, which will fail loudly and give you an error to work with if there is one.

Comment: is the entry recorded in database. I also see a typo error in your code when you initialize the model with values.

Comment: The entry is recorded in the database. I tried a save! prior as well, and it seems to be fine.

Comment: @StephenC you have a syntax error: `n = Notification.new :name => "#{self.sender.smart_name}...` - you're never closing the open double quotes. Change your `new` method to `n = Notification.new :name => "#{self.sender.smart_name} sent you a message:", :user_id => self.receiver_id, :notification_type => 'message', :subject => self.subject`

Comment: Thanks michael. Apologies I trimmed it and forgot to close it for the example. Updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should call  n.reload after n.save just to get the timestamps read after save